# Illegal Buffer with mango query in Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem:**

I have created a Hyperledger fabric network which consists of 6 organizations and 2 peers per each. And I have installed a chaincode on 6 peers of that and I have configured 6 couch Db instances with those peers where I have installed chaincode.
I do all other transaction of my chaincode successfully except the one I am running a mango query. Here is my function where I am running a mango query.

```
 async nthUsersLands(stub, args) {

    let nic = args[0];

    const query = JSON.stringify({
      selector: {
        docType: "land",
        owner: nic
      }
    });

    console.log(typeof query);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(query));

    let landsAsBytes = await stub.getQueryResult(query);

    console.log(landsAsBytes.toString());
    return landsAsBytes;
  }
```

This is how I am calling this function through cli.

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C myc -n mycc -c '{"Args":["nthUsersLands","942990014V"]}'
```

This leaves me this error on chaincode peer.

```
> 2019-06-10T02:56:56.937Z error [_]                                    
> error: Unhandled Rejection reason TypeError: Illegal buffer promise
> Promise {   <rejected> TypeError: Illegal buffer
>     at Function.module.exports.ByteBuffer.wrap (/usr/local/src/node_modules/bytebuffer/dist/bytebuffer-node.js:378:23)
>     at Element.ProtoBuf.Reflect.ElementPrototype.verifyValue (/usr/local/src/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:1886:39)
>     at Field.ProtoBuf.Reflect.FieldPrototype.verifyValue (/usr/local/src/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:3499:33)
>     at Message.ProtoBuf.Reflect.MessagePrototype.encode (/usr/local/src/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:3139:57)
>     at MessagePrototype.encode (/usr/local/src/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:2675:27)
>     at MessagePrototype.encodeNB (/usr/local/src/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:2770:37)
>     at handleMessage (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:658:35)
>     at <anonymous>
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) } {"timestamp":"2019-06-10T02:56:56.937Z"}
```

I tried a lot to find a solution to this problem But I am unable to do so. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to [marbles chaincode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/chaincode/marbles02/node/marbles_chaincode.js) from the fabric samples to get a clear view on using mango selector strings
I have pasted the following set of codes for your reference,make sure whether your chaincode has this methods..

```
async queryMarblesByOwner(stub, args, thisClass) {
//   0
// 'bob'
if (args.length < 1) {
  throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting owner name.')
}

let owner = args[0].toLowerCase();
let queryString = {};
queryString.selector = {};
queryString.selector.docType = 'marble';
queryString.selector.owner = owner;
let method = thisClass['getQueryResultForQueryString'];
let queryResults = await method(stub, JSON.stringify(queryString), thisClass);
return queryResults; //shim.success(queryResults);
}

//query result method

async getQueryResultForQueryString(stub, queryString, thisClass) {

console.info('- getQueryResultForQueryString queryString:\n' + queryString)
let resultsIterator = await stub.getQueryResult(queryString);
let method = thisClass['getAllResults'];

let results = await method(resultsIterator, false);

return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(results));
```

}
and also check on your nic variable as it points to args[0] which is your method name

Comment: thisClass is referring to what?

Comment: Should I pass it as a parameter or does it automatically refer to the class of the chaincode?

Comment: I solved thisClass problem. But now I am getting an error like.TypeError: Cannot read property 'getQueryResultForQueryString' of undefined

Comment: this class is reffering to the same class(chaincode main class)

Answer (score 0):

```
let landsAsBytes = await stub.getQueryResult(query);
```

it returns a `StateQueryIterator` object so you cannot convert it directly into a string.

---

- Here the official Shim documentation for getQueryResult:

  [HL Fabric Shim - getQueryResult](https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.4/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#getQueryResult__anchor)
- In order to optimize the query performances is recomended to create
  couchDB indexes:

  [HL Fabric Create couchDB indexes](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/couchdb_tutorial.html#cdb-create-index)
- The fabric-samples repository contains useful chaincode examples:

  [HL Fabric Samples Repository](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/chaincode)